# XSD Code Generator

Tags: xml, xsd, code-generation

Are there any Code Generators that would take a well-formed XML document, and write out an XSD schema based on how the XML document is structured?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The XSD.exe utility (which is installed with Visual Studio) is capable of creating an XSD file from an XML file.

Here's the link on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx)

I believe it may also part of the .NET SDK, meaning you would not need a full-blown Visual Studio installation.

Comment: I'm trying to find the file on my harddrive. Where's the darned thing located?

Comment: if you open a vs command prompt, just type xsd

Comment: Ah. I was looking for the physical .exe file. Silly me.  I finally found it in %Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin

Comment: Weird, I didnt know xsd could do inference too  :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

**Best Answer, bar none:**

http://xsd2code.codeplex.com

I pulled my hair out for a full 8 hr work day, got nowhere with all the crappy solutions out there (XSD, CodeXS, XSDObjectGen, and others) and am not interested in paying $400 for the stupid commercial tools just to do this.

Then I came across this codeplex project...  WOW!  Where was this all my life?

And the best part... its actively being worked on, right NOW (2009), not an abaondoned crust pile from 2004 or some lame thing.

Enjoy!

Comment: Looks great. Too bad it doesn't have a command-line version.

Comment: Correction: it DOES have a command-line version. Great!

Comment: Very nice find! This is how code *should* be generated!

Comment: The ongoing dev *is* nice. It has gone from unuseable (for me) a few bug reports and feature requests and now it's perfect for what I need.

Comment: Great tool, but it doesn't look like this does what the question asker is requesting. This creates C# classes from XSD schema, not a schema from a well formed XML document. Not worth a downvote though :)

Comment: Igor, would you share, how did you call Xsd2Code using windows command line to generate xsd out of an xml with data?

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio does it pretty well too... Open XML file.. Choose 'Generate Schema' Command from XML menu

Comment: This command may be running the XSD tool behind the scenes... Unfortuantely, I had to move to a different machine and do not have VS.Net installed yet to verify this.

Comment: I doubt it's the same tool, the ouput XSD inferred from the same XML file was quite different - and the Visual Studio version looked more correct !

Comment: It definitely does run xsd.exe. You may get different results due to the various parameters you can provide to it.

Comment: I dispute boomhauer's remark here.  I have a massive 40 megabyte file which xsd is choking on and Visual Studio manages fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am a little late to the part, but I find that [Businessware Architects CodeXS](http://www.bware.biz/default.htm?http://www.bware.biz/DotNet/Tools/CodeXS/WebClient/GenerateInput.aspx) is very good. I have found that it handles complex schema's much better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm note sure it is useful. After all, it cannot infer everything: if an element is present in the XML document, how to know if it is mandatory or not?

[Examplotron](http://examplotron.org/), to achieve a similar goal, relies, at least partly, on annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Try XXSd2Code. It code generates C#, C++, Java and C++/CLI bindings from xsds.
[XXSd2Code](http://xxsd2code.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

And old question I know but this might help someone: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html. Simple online tool and gets the job done with ease. Perfect for quick XML schema generation.