# XSD file to validate XMLs

Tags: validation, xsd

Can anybody help me to build an XSD file to validate XMLs like these:

```
[test]
[a/]
[b/]
[a/]
[b/]
[/test]

[test]
[a/]
[a/]
[b/]
[/test]
```

Basically, I can have any number of `<a>` and/or `<b>` nodes without any other rule (can't use `<xs:sequence>`).

Comment: Your syntax is hard to understand. Why don't you paste sample XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't going to very fast if you have a lot of **a** or **b** nodes but this validates against what you've described.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="test">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="a"/>
          <xs:element name="b"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the sample XML, we can help you better. However, [Microsoft has an XSD code generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288236/xsd-code-generator) that generates an XSD based on an XML file that you pass in as an argument.